# Using lapply to fit multiple model -- how to keep the model formula self-contained in lm object

Tags: r, regression, lapply

The following code fits 4 different model formulas to the `mtcars` dataset, using either for loop or lapply. In both cases, the formula stored in the result is referred to as `formulas[[1]]`, `formulas[[2]]`, etc. instead of the human-readable formula.

```
formulas <- list(
  mpg ~ disp,
  mpg ~ I(1 / disp),
  mpg ~ disp + wt,
  mpg ~ I(1 / disp) + wt
)
res <- vector("list", length=length(formulas))
for (i in seq_along(formulas)) {
  res[[i]] <- lm(formulas[[i]], data=mtcars)
}
res
lapply(formulas, lm, data=mtcars)
```

Is there a way to make the full, readable formula show up in the result?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work

```
lapply(formulas, function(x, data) eval(bquote(lm(.(x),data))), data=mtcars)
```

And it retruns

```
[[1]]

Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ disp, data = data)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)         disp  
   29.59985     -0.04122  


[[2]]

Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ I(1/disp), data = data)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)    I(1/disp)  
      10.75      1557.67  

....etc
```

We use `bquote` to insert the formula into the call to `lm` and then evaluate the expression.

Comment: Nice.  I was thinking `substitute` might also work, but this seems more fitting (no pun intended).

Answer (score 2):

Why not just:

```
lapply( formulas, function(frm) lm( frm, data=mtcars))
#------------------
[[1]]

Call:
lm(formula = frm, data = mtcars)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)         disp  
   29.59985     -0.04122  

[[2]]

Call:
lm(formula = frm, data = mtcars)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)    I(1/disp)  
      10.75      1557.67  
snpped....
```

If you wanted the names of the result to have the 'character'-ized version of the formulas it would just be"

```
 names(res) <- as.character(formulas)
 res[1]
#-----
$`mpg ~ disp`

Call:
lm(formula = frm, data = mtcars)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)         disp  
   29.59985     -0.04122
```

Comment: As your example shows, the call stored in the lm object is not fully human readable (i.e. `mpg ~ disp`), but just `frm`. This poses difficulty if I want to extract the call from the lm object later without having the `formulas` list being present. I think it's better to have the lm object being self-contained.

Answer (score 0):

you can also try something like

```
library(purrr)
library(tibble)
models <- map(formulas, lm, data = mtcars)
models
```